# Interesting BMO Final Selection Test Problem 1998 Q3

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

> An infinite arithmetic progression, whose terms are all positive integers, contains
> (i) a perfect square which is not a perfect cube, and
> (ii) a perfect cube which is not a perfect square.
> Prove that the arithmetic progression contains a perfect sixth power.

Finding examples where the base is the same is trivial but to find a general proof I tried looking at examples where square and cube are co-prime (hence common difference d is also co-prime with these) and using mod d and Euler's theorem to come up with a relatively short algebraic proof however, nothing has immediately opened up.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried.

Comment: For example  A. progression of the form $2, 4, 6, 8, . . . 64 . . .$ has $4=2^2$, $8=2^3$ and $64=2^6$,Or: $3, 6, 9, . . . 27 . . . 729 . . .$ has $9=3^2$, $27=3^3$ and $729= 3^6$.

Comment: Aren't the conditions an overkill though? If a perfect square is also a perfect cube (or the other way around), then the conclusion trivially holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that there exist $x$, $y$ with $x^2\equiv y^3\equiv a\pmod n$. Let $d$ be the order of $a$ mod $n$.

If $d=1$, we are done as $x^6\equiv1\pmod n$. If $n=2$, then $(xy)^6\equiv a^5\equiv a\pmod n$, and again we are done.

So assume $d>2$. For any $i,j$ we have $(x^iy^j)^6\equiv a^{3i+2j}\pmod n$. By the [Chicken McNugget theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem), there exist $i,j$ such that $3i+2j=m$ for all $m>6-2-3=1$. Since $d-1>1$, we can find $i,j$ such that $3i+2j=d-1$, so
$$(x^iy^j)^6\equiv a^{d-1}\pmod n\implies\left(x^{i(d-1)}y^{j(d-1)}\right)^6\equiv a^{(d-1)^2}\equiv a\pmod n,$$
and we are done!

Comment: Why modulo n?..

Comment: @N.S. $n$ is the common difference of the arithmetic progression, i.e. I'm taking the arithmetic progression to be $a+nt$ for $t=0,1,\dots$